Прижать слой в qt к верху окна, чтобы он не перемещался и не пытался занять доступное место
Делаю виджет, который будет отображать переданные в него виджеты как в таблице (принимает два параметра - количество виджетов в строке и какую часть экрана занимает каждый виджет).
Иерархия:
QScrollArea
    QWidget container
        QVBoxLayout mainLayout
            QHBoxLayout btnLayout
            QGridLayout gridLayout

Конструктор cpp
    // контейнер для всех виджетов
    container = new QWidget(this);
    // компоновщик на контейнер
    mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(container);
    container->setLayout(mainLayout);

    // слой для кнопок (находится на одном уровне со слоем с виджетами)
    btnLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    addWidgetBtn = new QPushButton("Добавить");
    removeWidgetBtn = new QPushButton("Удалить");

    btnLayout->addWidget(addWidgetBtn);
    btnLayout->addWidget(removeWidgetBtn);

    mainLayout->addLayout(btnLayout);

    connect(addWidgetBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &GridWidget::addWidget);
    connect(removeWidgetBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &GridWidget::removeWidget);

    // устанавливаем виджет-контейнер в QScrollArea
    this->setWidget(container);

Из за компоновщика выходит следующее 


Каким образом я могу прибить слой с кнопками к верху или к низу (причем, чтобы при ресайзе он также растягивался горизонтально, но всегда был либо внизу либо вверху)?
Если прибиваю таким способ:
mainLayout->addStretch();

то кнопки прибиваются, но их слой все равно занимает все доступное место


mainLayout->item(0)->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop) или сразу для всего mainLayout->setAligment(Qt::AlignTop)

mainLayout->QVBoxLayout::itemAt(0)->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
Сработало, но отображаемые виджеты учитывают размер слоя с кнопками и между ними появляются отступы, насколько мне известно, задать размеры слоя нельзя(

Если вы хотите, чтобы все виджеты были прижаты к верху, накидывайте выравнивание на весь компоновщик mainLayout->setAligment(Qt::AlignTop)
